# How to start Docker containers on boot, managed with Ansible (Tower)

Tags: docker, ansible

Currently we use the combination of Ansible + Ansible Tower to deploy and run our applications in Docker containers.

However, I was wondering how to automatically run the deployed containers after a system reboot. What would be the way to go here? The only solution we came up with is to automatically request the Tower callback URL of the application deployment playbook(s) on boot, but that seems suboptimal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [restart policies](https://blog.docker.com/2014/08/announcing-docker-1-2-0/).

I do not know how exactly `ansible` creates containers. But usually you could add a parameter on command line like:

```
docker run --restart=always ...
```

Comment: I think these only apply for containers restarts when a container crashes, not when an entire server reboots? Or am I wrong?

Comment: When a container crashes there is an explicit `--restart=on-failure:5` option. When you use `--restart=always` the container will be always started.

Comment: Did some testing and you're right, thanks. I was assuming that the docker restart argument was just for container failures. The Ansible equivalent is `restart_policy: always`

Answer (score 6):

```
restart_policy: always
```

or

```
restart_policy: unless-stopped
```

link:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_container_module.html